Loss of ST-LINK from STM32F4
I am using is STM32F401RET6, before that I have ported uCOS-II and System View to see the task scheduling, but Sysview needs to use J-Link, so I followed the tutorials (https://www.segger.com/products/debug-probes/j-link/models/other-j-links/st-link-on-board/) given by SEGGER to convert the ST-LINK/V2-1 that comes with the development version to J-LINK. However, there was an accident during the conversion process, resulting in the loss of ST-LINK, and I can't burn the programme. Please tell me if there is a way to remedy the situation.
Currently I use an external ST-LINK to burn programs, but this way I can't power the whole STM32, which means I still need an external power supply, which is extremely inconvenient. Anyway, is there any way to restore the original ST-LINK?

From your link, did you read the part about restoring original firmware? Did you contact Segger support if it does not work?

Thanks. I rechecked and finally realised that it was the version of J-LINK I had installed that was not adapted, causing the PC to not detect the
